# "Undefined reference to function" error

Tags: c, include, compiler-errors

I am having some trouble compiling a few files using headers. Here is a breakdown of my code:

**file1.c**

```
#include "header.h"
int main() {
    func1();
    return 0;
}
```

**file2.c**

```
#include "header.h"
void func1() {
    ... function implementation ...
}
```

**header.h**

```
void func1();
```

The error I am getting is:

> In function `'main'`:
>   undefined reference to `'func1'`

Note: I am just using a simple breakdown of how my 3 files are set up. I need to get this to work with the 3 files. I am setting/including everything properly? I need to use this set up, but I am just unsure how file.c gets reference to the actually implementation of `func1()`.

Comment: what compiler are you using ?? can you provide your compiler statement?

Comment: If you're using `gcc -o program file2.c file1.c`, change this to `gcc -o program file1.c file2.c`. Order is important.

Comment: Hmm, your right that this should work under normal gcc compiling. Problem is, this issue for more is from a very big project, with hundreds of files. But the structure of the problem is the same. I just thought maybe I wasn't including stuff properly, but I guess that's not the case.

Comment: I just tried this with gcc -- gcc -o test file2.c file1.c -- using file1.c and file2.c in both positions. Something else is afoot, I think. I'm on Ubuntu 10.04 gcc version 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1)

Comment: @H2CO3 - WHAT?!?!?  How in the world is order important for this?  Both orders work fine for me.  I don't get the undefined reference either way.

Comment: @phonetagger GCC looks for symbols in the order they're needed to be resolved. If you specify a wrong order, you may get "undefined reference" errors.

Comment: Yes I am, but I'm not sure how much my environment is a result of this. The interaction is between 3 files, as I described, but the project I'm working on is for school and is really big (we're implementing a simulated OS based on Harvard's OS/161 system). Still, I am not sure why it cannot find reference to the function.

Comment: @H2CO3 - I'd like to see an example of what you're saying, or perhaps a link to some page that describes it.  The error Tesla's seeing is a linker error, not a compiler error.  At the linking stage, functions in one file should be able to call functions in another file, and vice-versa.  I'm pretty sure the linker should have no problem doing its job regardless of the order the files were specified.

Comment: @Tesla - Since your project is really big, I'm assuming you're surely using a makefile or have a Visual Studio solution+project setup.  Is it possible you added a new source file & didn't include it in your makefile/project file list?

Comment: @phonetagger I know what the difference between linker and compiler errors is.

Comment: @H2CO3: AFAIK, the order matters only for libraries. I.e. libs (`-lnameoflib`) should be specified after the sources using symbols from them, and if there are inter-lib dependencies, then order of libs matters too, or the grouping options must be used (linker then goes in a loop for the group, until all references are satisfied or no more can be resolved.)

Comment: @H2CO3 Order matters only for linking static libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the error is an undefined reference to `func1()`, *and there is no other error*, then I would think it's because you have two files called `header.h` in your project and the other copy is being included instead of your copy with the declaration of `func1()`.

I would check the include paths for your project and make sure that the `header.h` with your declaration of `func1()` is being included first.

Comment: This is soooooo old, but I am running into the issue and I'd appreciate help. The basic set up is the same as this question, except I am sure that correct header is being included, because some functions do not give undefined references and some do. It's just weird, and if I jeopardize the header then the code "correctly" doesn't compile.